# Jenkins: How to pass python script variable to groovy?

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy

Here is the python script, simply reading the `Period (yyyy-mm)` from file name:

```
Path = os.path.join("Operators", "To_Process{}".format(os.sep))
l_file = pd.Series([os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(Path + "*")])

Period = l_file.str.extract(r"(\d{4}-\d{2})").max()[0]

print(Period)
```

And here is the my pipeline in Jenkins, I'm not sure about how to properly pass the result of the `sh` script to my variable, the code below is not working:

```
def Period = ''

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'toto'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Parallel'){
            parallel {
                stage('1') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            label 'toto...'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                        sh script: Period = 'python script.py'
                    }
                }
                
                stage('2') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'python -V'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITS 1**

After some modification is seems the pipeline execute without issue BUT, the variable `Period` is not assigned and remains empty:
Could it be that calling `print(Period)` does not return any value ?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'toto'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Parallel'){
            parallel {
                stage('1') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            label 'toto...'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                        script {
                                Period = sh(script:'python script.py', returnStdout: true)
                        }
                        echo Period
                    }
                }

                stage('2') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'python -V'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: look at additional parameters for `sh` https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

Comment: @daggett, I've tried but it's still not working, see my Edits with the things I've tried. The pipeline is executing now but the Variable is not assigned